# gradle - create jar iteratively under a certain directory

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to create multiple jars. I have a certain directory which contains multiple directory. Each directory has its own files(xml and sql). So I am trying to create a jar with a subdirectory name and all the files in it. Those jars will be used for junit test, so I want to create it during configuration phase in advance.

The target directory "../dist" exists outside this project.

```
ext.createTemplateJar = { sourceDirectory, jarFileName ->
    jar {
        archiveName = jarFileName
        from sourceDirectory
        includeEmptyDirs = false
        manifest 
        {
            attributes  'Implementation-Title'      : VENDOR_NAME
        }
    }   
    println "creating a jar for ${jarFileName}"
}

tasks.withType(Jar) {
    destinationDir = file("../dist")
}

task generateTemplates {
    new File("${projectDir}/templates").eachFile() { file ->
        if (file.isFile()) {
            return
        }
        println "template dir is ${file.path}"
        createTemplateJar(file.path, "${file.name}.jar")
    }    
}
```

When I execute this gradle generateTemplates, it runs fine, but I don't see any jar files created in the destination directory.

It seems something wrong, but I can't tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create multiple `Jar` tasks, one for each subdirectory inside `${projectDir}/templates`, and have your `generateTemplates` task do nothing but depend on all of those tasks. For example (I renamed `generateTemplates` to `allJars`):

```
task allJars {
}

file("${projectDir}/templates").eachFile { f ->
    def taskName = "jar${f.name.capitalize()}"
    tasks.create(name: taskName, type: Jar) {
        archiveName = "${f.name}.jar"
        destinationDir = file('../dist')
        // Configure each JAR however you want
    }
    allJars.dependsOn taskName
}
```

Example build:

```
$ ls templates/
bar  baz  foo  test

$ ./gradlew clean allJars
:clean
:jarBar
:jarBaz
:jarFoo
:jarTest
:allJars

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.615 secs

$ ls ../dist/
bar.jar  baz.jar  foo.jar  test.jar
```